# How to validate null or empty space input in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to validate a string input to prevent it from being null or empty. I tried using pattern matching but it always prints error no matter the input. I feel like I had to add another pattern to represent all other input but I don't know how to write it.

```
let qwe = ""
let validate x =
    match x with
    | qwe -> printfn "error"

printf "Enter your pet's name: "
let petname = Console.ReadLine()
validate petname
```

I've tried to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` but had more issues with that. If possible could you please reference some sources where I can read up on this issue or validation in F# in general.

Comment: "*I've tried to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` but had more issues with that.*" Like what? It takes a string and returns a bool, hard to imagine what issue you could have.

Comment: It always prints "error" because that's what you have programmed "validate" to do. The two "qwe" are not the same. You misunderstand what the second "qwe" is. The "error" will always be printed. When there is a warning, make sure you understand what it means.

Comment: I see where I have gone completely wrong, thanks for pointing about that dumb error of mine. Just learnt about pattern matching today and it seems I didn't go over it properly, sorry about that and thanks

Comment: @ildjarn Realised where I was going wrong with that as well I just forgot to write the else condition at the end of my if statement, making a lot of dumb mistakes today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match on an empty string or `null`, you have to use the literal values:

```ml
let validate x =
    match x with
    | null -> "null string"
    | "" -> "empty string"
    | _ -> "something else"
```

Your code above is creating a second value called `qwe` that binds to whatever value `x` has. That's why it always prints "error".

Comment: In particular, it's called a variable pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#variable-patterns

Comment: thanks I just learnt about pattern matching and made a dumb error now that I look at it again

Comment: @PhillipCarter thank you I will go over it

Comment: No problem. It's an easy mistake to make. Probably everyone here responding has done the same thing at some point. :)

Comment: I did it once. Do not tell anybody.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the accepted answer, you can also use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` with a `when` clause:

```ml
let validate x =
    match x with
    | s when String.IsNullOrEmpty s -> "error" 
    | s -> s
```

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching works differently in different languages. For example in Erlang it works as *if variable with same name found, then match will success if value to match equals to value in variable. If variable not found, then match will always success*:

```erlang
// test code in  http://tpcg.io/NTA1YF 
-module(helloworld).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    Empty = "",
    Null = nil,
    Input = "zxc", % you can change this string to write different outputs
    Output = case Input of
        Empty -> "Empty string\n";
        Null -> "Null\n";
        X -> io_lib:format("Input is: ~p\n", [X])
    end,
    io:fwrite(Output).
```

But F# have [different behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching) and almost always matching against variable succeeds (rules are consistent, but complex).

In my opinion best way is to use [active patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns) as they are clear and composable way to extend pattern matching:

```ml
open System

let inline (|NullOrEmpty|_|) s = 
    if String.IsNullOrEmpty s then 
        Some()
    else 
        None

let validate x =
    match x with
    | NullOrEmpty -> failwith "null or empty string"
    | _ -> ()

printf "Enter your pet's name: "
let petname = Console.ReadLine()
validate petname
```

Comment: Thank you very much